# MouseHover event runs a milliseconds slower in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, events, mousehover

I've noticed something when I use Mousehover event, that it is slower in some milliseconds.
I mean that when I point my cursor on it, it is few milliseconds slower. please help me How to fix this

Here's my code:

```
    Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
    Button1.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Button1.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub
End Class
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use the `Enter` or `MouseEnter` events (since it's a Button, probably the latter), not `MouseHover`

Comment: i used it for user interface like when mouse hover the color change and mouse leave the color change not the function. i hope you understood this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use MouseMove event instead of MouseHover, that will do it for you. It gives you an immediate response.

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove
    Button1.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Best wishes!

-BHARATHI Tutorials